# python3 + selenium - looping through every element from website problem

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to make a script that opens every element in the same class one by one. But after executing driver.back() command the loop is ending.

Here is the example of the content i have used:

```
 <div id="123" class="abc"></div>
 <div id="345" class="abc"></div>
 <div id="456" class="abc"></div>
```

Here is the code:

```
material = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('abc')
for x in material:
    x.click()
    driver.back()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm totally stuck. Thank you!